# Disable parallax iOS in UIAlertController

Tags: ios, ios8, parallax, uialertcontroller

The app I'm developing only supports portrait mode. However, in iOS8, the now deprecated `UIAlertView` can go into landscape and displays some other minor problems. In order to fix this, I have decided to give the `UIAlertController` a try. It works, but I have a new problem which is still a bit annoying. The alert no longer goes into landscape, but it does feature the parallax motion thing. I've added a label and an image to the `UIAlertController`'s view, but those do not feature the parallax thing, meaning it looks pretty weird when users move the phone around.

I'm looking for two options, but I can't find how to do either of them.
The first solution would be to disable the parallax thing, seeing how we don't support it anywhere in the app.
The second solution is to add the parallax support to the label and image.
Anyway, here's the piece of code:

```
UIAlertController *welcomeAlertController = [UIAlertController
                                              alertControllerWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Would you like to send %@ a message?", @"This message is displayed after adding a new message receiver. The %@ is the name of the receiver."), self.receiver.name]
                                              message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Skip", @"Skip: meaning user can skip a certain step.")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   [self cancelButtonPressed];
                               }];

UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                           actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Send", @"Send: meaning user can send information to somewhere.")
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                           {
                               [self sendButtonClicked];
                           }];

[welcomeAlertController addAction:cancelAction];
[welcomeAlertController addAction:okAction];

smsView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 240, 95);
messageBackgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 80);

warningLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 170, 240, 40);
warningLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[welcomeAlertController.view addSubview:smsView];  // An UIView
[welcomeAlertController.view addSubview:warningLabel];

[self presentViewController:welcomeAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/2jexyl/help_required_with_uialertcontroller_ios8), after a couple days no reply, so asked him to post here.

Comment: I plan to award the bounty in the grace period to the currently accepted answer, unless someone knows how to turn parallax off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a parallax to the views is deadly simple. It works like this:

```
UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
horizontalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-30);
horizontalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(30);

UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalMotionEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
verticalMotionEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(-30);
verticalMotionEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(30);

UIMotionEffectGroup *group = [UIMotionEffectGroup new];
group.motionEffects = @[horizontalMotionEffect, verticalMotionEffect];
[yourViewHere addMotionEffect:group];
```

You might want to play with the values `@(30)` to define the way it all looks.

And as far as I'm concerned, you can't turn off the parallax on `UIAlertController` and you might want to implement your own UI copy of that by subclassing a `UIView`.

Comment: I can't up vote your answer yet, but thanks for answering my question. It's going to take a bit of tweaking to match that of the UIAlertController but at least I can continue. +1 (if I could)

Comment: The effect does some to stutter a bit compared to the "native" movement of the uialertcontroller, but it works. Thanks again

Comment: @user1945317 glad I could help. The effect is actually how `UIAlertController` works, simply because I had to implement the exact same copy of `UIAlertView` once and compared them on real devices. Well, at least it's as close as we can get.

Comment: Will award the bounty to this during the grace period, unless someone else shows up with a way to disable parallax.